# How can I properly read json data from ajax response?

Tags: json, ajax, reactjs, typescript, axios

I did something like this:

```
axios.get(url).then(result => {
   this.setState({
     list: result.data,
   });
})
.catch(e => { 
   console.log("Some error", e);
});
```

Constructor looks like this:

```
constructor(props: any) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
       list: [],
   };
}
```

I want to put it somewhere and check whether it works:

```
const {fetchedData}: any = this.state;
const data: IScheduler = fetchedData.list;
```

but I get uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'list' of undefined...

It works when I do that this way:

```
const data: IScheduler = {
      generatedDate: "03.12.2017";
      subjects: [
          ....
      ],
};
```

But it's not the point. What am I doing wrong? How should I fix it? Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your state there is no property `fetchedData`. You set your list to this.state.list, not to `this.state.fetchedData.list`. So you need to change your code from:

```
const {fetchedData}: any = this.state;
const data: IScheduler = fetchedData.list;
```

to:

```
const {list}: any = this.state;
const data: IScheduler = list;
```

It should work. If you really want your first data structure you need to change your default state structure and `setState`, but **nested data structure is not recommended**.

```
axios.get(url).then(result => {
   this.setState({
     fetchedData: {
       list: result.data
     }
   });
})
.catch(e => { 
   console.log("Some error", e);
});
```

Constructor should looks like this:

```
constructor(props: any) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
       fetchedData: {
         list: []
       }
   };
}
```

Comment: Thank you! One more question. I want to write generatedDate property into console (just to make sure everything will be working). So I typed: console.log(data.generatedDate); but I get the same error. How can I do this?

Comment: without knowing the data structure, I can not help, but i geuss the data doesn't exist jet try to console.log(data).

Comment: Hmm.. for the sake of this example IScheduler structure would be like this { generatedDate: string; } and json data would be { "generatedDate": "03.12.2017", }. console.log(data.generatedDate) should write into console '03.12.2017' but the error occurs. When I try to console.log(data) , I get 'undefined'.

Comment: I changed constructor. Now console.log(data) writes an state array into console without generatedDate property. Anyway thanks for your help.